# different between node http Headers and rawHeaders

Tags: node.js, http, https

I don't find any raw headers in http request Architecture. So where from it's come. I search it on internet but don't find any usefull content.

Comment: From the node.js [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_message_rawheaders). In `rawHeaders` the "Header names are not lowercased, and duplicates are not merged."

Comment: so what is the use case of this

Comment: The main "use case" is for generating the `headers`.. If you wanna know how `headers` handling duplicates you read [here](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_message_headers).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

rawHeaders
https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_message_rawheaders

- Exactly as they were received.
- Header names are not lowercased.
- duplicates are not merged.

headers
https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_message_headers

- Header names are lower-cased.
- Duplicates are merged.

Answer (score 1):

[rawHeaders](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_message_rawheaders) has the request/response headers list **exactly** as they were received ("So, the even-numbered offsets are key values, and the odd-numbered offsets are the associated values").

[headers](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_message_headers) has an object converted from `rawHeaders`.